# Make list via functional programming in Python

Tags: python, list, functional-programming

What is the correct syntax of the following:

```
[for elem in [1,2,3] 10 if elem < 2 else 50]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[10 if elem < 2 else 50
 for elem in [1,2,3]]
```

(newline merely for emphasis)

Answer (score 0):

Same with `map()` that some might consider "more functional" than list comprehension.

```py
map(lambda val:  10 if val < 2 else 50, [1,2,3]))
```